# Oracle database 12C restore script

Tags: restore, oracle-12c, scripting, rman

i'm trying to create backup restore script .
in short my backup script creating new directory every day from the operating system level and then backup the database using the directory created

i tried the below script but it seems RMAN doesn't recognize the controlfiles
here is my script

```
**#RMAN RESTORE SCRIPT** 
#!/bin/bash
#Environment Variables

ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1    
ORACLE_SID=cdb11    
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin    
DD=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`    
export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID PATH DD controlfile backupsets    
controlfile=/ArchiveDBBackup/DAILY_RMAN/${DD}/CDB1_CONTROLFILE    
backupsets=/ArchiveDBBackup/DAILY_RMAN/${DD}/    
export controlfile backupsets    

LOGFILE=/RMAN/log/DAILY_FULLBKP_RESTORE_`date +%Y%m%d`.log    
rman target / LOG $LOGFILE <<EOF
run
{
shutdown immediate;
startup nomount;
set dbid=961936136
restore controlfile FROM '$controlfile';
alter database mount;
catalog start with '$backupsets' noprompt;
restore database;
recover database;
alter database open resetlogs;
exit
}

EOF
```

**Error :-**

> RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 07/04/2021 09:35:57
> RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece

any idea how can RMAN recognize linux variables ? or anyway to achieve the restore with those variables ?

Comment: Singly-quoted strings are not interpolated by any shell I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following:

```
controlfile=/ArchiveDBBackup/DAILY_RMAN/${DD}/CDB1_CONTROLFILE
```

to be:

```
controlfile='/ArchiveDBBackup/DAILY_RMAN/${DD}/CDB1_CONTROLFILE'
```

Then try again.